# Can a multidimensional array be filled from variadic template?

Tags: c++11, multidimensional-array, variadic-templates

So i have something like that:

```
template<unsigned int W,unsigned int H>
class Class
{
    int data[W][H];
    Class(const (&_data)[W][H])
    {
        for (int x=0;x<W;x++)
            for (int y=0;y<H;y++)
                data[x][y] = _data[x][y];
    }
    template<class... args>
    Class()
    {
        /// black magic
    }
}
```

What could i replace the "black magic", so the second constructor will accept W*H ints?
Example:

```
Class<3,2> class1(1,2,3,4,5,6);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use [std::initializer_list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) as a constructor parameter, since your array only is of type `int[][]`.

```
Class(std::initializer_list<int> il)
{
    if(il.size() < W*H)
        throw string("Insufficient elements");//if lesser no. of elements are given.
    auto it = il.begin();// iterator to the first element of the list.
    for(int i =0;i< W;++i)
    {
        for(int j =0; j < H;++j)
        {
            data[i][j] = *it++;// increment the iterator
        }
    }
}
```

call site will look like this:

```
Class<3,2> c{1,2,3,4,5,6};
```

or

```
Class<3,2> c = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
```

if more elements are given then extras are discarded. `initializer_list` can give type safety, and will give you  a diagnostic if narrowing is found.

Answer (score 3):

There are alternative answers which might be more practical and simpler to implement, but I'll show how you could actually do this with a compile-time for-loop for purposes of demonstrating black-magic.

Here is a compile-time for-loop.

```
/* Compile-time for-loop up to N. */
template <std::size_t N>
struct For {

  /* Call f<I>(args...) N times. */
  template <typename F, typename... Args>
  void operator()(F &&f, Args &&... args) const {
    Impl<0, N>()(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }

  private:

  /* Forward declaration. */
  template <std::size_t I, std::size_t End>
  struct Impl;

  /* Base case. Do nothing. */
  template <std::size_t End>
  struct Impl<End, End> {

    template <typename F, typename... Args>
    void operator()(F &&, Args &&...) const { /* Do nothing. */ }

  };  // Impl<End, End>

  /* Recursive case. Call f<I>(args...), then recurse into next step. */
  template <std::size_t I, std::size_t End>
  struct Impl {

    template <typename F, typename... Args>
    void operator()(F &&f, Args &&... args) const {
      std::forward<F>(f).template operator()<I>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
      Impl<I + 1, End>()(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

  };  // Impl<I, End>

};  // For<N>
```

Here is a simple use case of it.

```
struct Print {

  template <std::size_t I>
  void operator()(int x, int y) const {
    std::cout << "Iteration " << I << ": " << x << ' ' << y << std::endl;
  }

};  // Print

For<3>()(Print(), 1, 2);
```

Outputs

```
Iteration 0: 1 2
Iteration 1: 1 2
Iteration 2: 1 2
```

Now with this we can nest this compile-time for-loop just like how we could nest a run-time for-loop. Here is the Matrix class using this For<> template.

```
/* Defines an M by N Matrix, (Row by Col). */
template <std::size_t M, std::size_t N>
class Matrix {
  public:

  /* Our underlying M by N matrix. */
  using Data = std::array<std::array<int, N>, M>;

  /* Construct off of M * N arguments. */
  template <typename... Args>
  Matrix(Args &&... args) {
    static_assert(sizeof...(Args) == M * N,
                  "The number of arguments provided must be M * N.");
    ForEach(AssignImpl(),
            data_,
            std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
  }

  /* Print each element out to std::cout. */
  void Write(std::ostream &strm) const {
    ForEach(WriteImpl(), strm, data_);
  }

  private:

  /* Our outer for loop. Call InnerFor() M times.
     Resembles: 'for (std::size_t i = 0 ; i < M; ++i) {' */
  template <typename F, typename... Args>
  void ForEach(F &&f, Args &&... args) const {
    For<M>()(InnerFor(), std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }

  /* Our inner for loop. Call ForBody() N times.
     Resembles: 'for (std::size_t j = 0; j < N; ++j) {' */
  struct InnerFor {

    template <std::size_t I, typename F, typename... Args>
    void operator()(F &&f, Args &&... args) const {
      For<N>()(ForBody<I>(),
               std::forward<F>(f),
               std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

  };  // InnerFor

  /* The body of our for loop. Call f<I, J>(args...); */
  template <std::size_t I>
  struct ForBody {

    template <std::size_t J, typename F, typename... Args>
    void operator()(F &&f, Args &&... args) const {
      std::forward<F>(f)
          .template operator()<I, J>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

  };  // ForBody<I>

  /* Given the M by N array and a tuple of length M * N, assign the array. */
  struct AssignImpl {

    template <std::size_t I, std::size_t J, typename Arg>
    void operator()(Data &data, Arg &&arg) const {
      data[I][J] = std::get<I * N + J>(std::forward<Arg>(arg));
    }

  };  // AssignImpl

  /* Given an output stream and our data, print the data at (I, J). */
  struct WriteImpl {

    template <std::size_t I, std::size_t J>
    void operator()(std::ostream &strm, const Data &data) const {
      strm << data[I][J] << std::endl;
    }

  };  // WriteImpl

  /* Our underlying M by N array. */
  Data data_;

};  // Matrix
```

Here is a quick demonstration of construction and writing to `std::cout`.

```
int main() {
  Matrix<3, 2> matrix{101, 102,
                      201, 202,
                      301, 302};
  matrix.Write(std::cout);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, there's some syntax errors in your example as missing semicolon after class declaration and the constructors being private.

Apart from that, if you want to store the numbers in [*row-major order*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order), then you should declare your matrix/2d-array as `int data[H][W]` (height first, then width).

To store the values from a variadic pack you can simply expand them inside the ctor of a container, e.g. [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), and make use of *list-initialization*.

```
template <typename... Args>
Class(Args&&... args) {
    const std::array<int, H * W> temp{std::forward<Args>(args)...};
    /* ... */
};
```

I've also used [universal references](http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) and perfect forwarding to preserve the reference type of the pack.

To populate your 2d-array you simply have to iterate over all elements in `temp` and store them in the member array.

```
for (std::size_t h = 0; h != H; ++h)
    for (std::size_t w = 0; w != W; ++w)
        data[h][w] = temp[h * W + w];
```

[**See a full example here**](http://ideone.com/1OwQ7r)

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
#include <array>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

template<unsigned W,unsigned H>
struct Foo
{
  std::array<std::array<int, H>, W> data;
  template<typename... Args>
  Foo(Args&&... args):
    data{ std::forward<Args>(args)... }
  {}
};
int main()
{
  Foo<2,2> x(1,2,3,4);
  for( auto&& a : x.data ) {
    for( unsigned z : a ) {
      std::cout << z << ",";
    }
  std::cout << "\n";
}
```

but exposes the order of storage in your inner `array`.

`std::array` is a syntactic sugar wrapped around raw C arrays.